# Django reverse nested filtering

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make a filter on a nested Model with the Django reverse relation. Below is the sample models I have :

```
class ProcessVersion(TimeStampedModel):

    tag = models.CharField(_('Tag Name'), max_length=48)
    status = FSMField(
        _('Status'), max_length=12, choices=VERSION_STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=VERSION_STATUS_IN_EDITION)


class Step(models.Model):


    version = models.ForeignKey(
        ProcessVersion, verbose_name=_('Process Version'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='steps', blank=True,
        null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('Is active'), default=False)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=32)


class Block(models.Model):


    step = models.ForeignKey(
        Step, verbose_name=_('Loan Process Step'), on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='blocks',  blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('Is active'), default=False)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=128, blank=True)
```

The first scenario was accessing the Step through it's related name and it worked :

```
process_version = ProcessVersion.objects.get(id=process_version_id)
            steps = process_version.steps.get(id=param_id)
```

meaning that I passed through `ProcessVersion` to get the `Step`.

Now, my question is what if I want to get the `Block` but passing through `ProcessVersion` with it's `id` , how can I query that ?

Comment: So you have `process_version_id`, and you want the `Block`(s) that have a `step` which has a `version` that corresponds to the `ProcessVersionId`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, when provided the `process_version_id`, and the `block_id`, I wanted to the blocks. This time around with no `step_id`

Comment: @But if there is no `step_id`, then how is the `Block` related to that `process_version_id`?

Comment: That's what I was wondering?, so there's no way to do this? accept we have the step_id ?

Comment: but it is not a metter of "not a way", it is a matter of making no sense. Since that block is not related to a `ProcessVersion` (directly or indirectly), it thus has nothing to do with the `ProcessVersion` if the `step` is `NULL`/`None`.

Comment: Makes sense, so I have to first go through `Step` to access the `blocks`